# Can apt-get upgrade perform a dist-upgrade from one version of debian stable to the next?

Tags: apt

I just wanted to do a regular upgrade on my Debian Wheezy system. I did the usual

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I noticed that the number of packages to be upgraded was pretty large but I just hit Y and proceeded with the upgrade.
To my astonishment, after the upgrade was finished, I found out that I now have a Debian 8 system.

So, is it possible that a simple `upgrade` has performed a `dist-upgrade`? As far as I understood, `upgrade` should never perform a distribution upgrade but only upgrade packages for the current distribution. Or am I missing something?

Here is my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main

# wheezy-backports
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

# debian multimedia non-free
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free

# xtreemfs
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/xtreemfs/Debian_7.0 ./

# MariaDB 5.5 repository list - created 2015-03-29 20:56 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/debian wheezy main
```

Anyway, is it possible to revert the system to a clean wheezy system in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

line in your `sources.list` means you're tracking `stable`, not `wheezy`; since `jessie` became `stable` last weekend you switched to Jessie.

The distinction between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` isn't related to performing "distribution" upgrades or not; `apt-get` doesn't actually really know you're changing distributions. The distinction is that `upgrade` won't remove packages, whereas `dist-upgrade` might if necessary. (The `dist-upgrade` does come from the fact that it's what should be used when upgrading the full distribution.)

Fixing your upgrade and reverting to Wheezy isn't supported; Debian packages aren't required to downgrade properly.

You should fix your `sources.list` to use a named version though rather than `stable`, to avoid such surprises in the future.

If you do want to try downgrading, specify `wheezy` instead of `stable` in `sources.list`. Then install `apt-show-versions` and use that to find packages which need downgrading; packages can be downgraded by installing them from `wheezy`, for example

```
apt-get install libc6/wheezy
```

(Don't start with `libc6` though, that will be one of the last packages you can downgrade.)

I'd recommend sticking with Jessie though!

Comment: The `stable` line was a copy-and-paste from some documentation. I'll have to be more careful in the future. Of course I would like to upgrade to jessie, but I want to do it properly (after performing an appropriate backup of configuration files).

Comment: I understand perfectly that you'd want to upgrade properly, but it's now too late to backup your configuration files, at least as they were in Wheezy — the unintended upgrade to Jessie will have changed some of them, and downgrading won't restore them. Check out [etckeeper](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/etckeeper) for future reference!

Comment: My system has not been upgraded properly: several packages that were installed (e.g. mariadb) are no longer available. I think I will install jessie to a free partition and start from scratch.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the explanations and the tips. `etckeeper` seems a great tool.

Comment: You're welcome! MariaDB came from their repository, and they don't have a Jessie repository yet; but their Sid repository has a good chance of still being compatible with Jessie, so you could always try that.

Comment: mariadb is still installed, but the executable is not in the path. I think I will go for a clean jessie install.

Comment: I ended up downgrading all packages using `apt-show-versions` as you suggested. At a certain point I had no kernel so I would not have been able to boot again. With some luck I could reinstall the old kernel and the system is back to wheezy now. It seems to work. In parallel I am trying out jessie and plan to move to it once I have understood how to configure it properly.